# Using twitter bootstrap locally

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded the needed js and css files so I can import and use them locally, but no matter what I do I always get a different results than the starter template provided by them!!

Th starter template example:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/starter-template/

My code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <link rel="icon" href="./imgs/logo.png">
        <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>
        <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main role="main" class="container">
            <div class="starter-template">
                <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
                <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
            </div>
        </main>
    <script src="./js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My question is, how can I use the new bootstrap locally? Thanks...

Edit:

[image]

Edit 2:

[image]

Comment: different in what way(s)?

Comment: The styling is different.

Answer (score 0):

Please note, that you have a dot in the beginning of path to a resource file: `href="./css/bootstrap.min.css"` (i mean the `./css` part).

It means that for the page on `http://localhost/` the browser is readying file by URL `http://localhost/css/bootstrap.min.css`

and for the page like `http://localhost/blog/` the browser is trying to read an URL `http://localhost/blog/css/bootstrap.min.css`, which is incorrect I suppose.

**Possible solution**: try to use links to resources files without dot

`<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`
`<script src="/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>`

and please check if your local web-server is working fine with those paths.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the dot before the directory will point to the directory in a normal way. However, I removed it, and still it has the same effect.